# Passing return value of one promise as a parameter for another

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Probably a very simple question, but here goes:

I'm using Bluebird promises, but I want to pass the value returned from one promise into another one as a parameter. My current code is thus:

```
Promise.props
  reports: @app.Reports.getReports()
  years: @app.Years.getYears()
.then (promised) =>
  console.log promised
```

But really I want to be able to use `promised.years` as the first parameter for `getReports`, so it would be something like `reports: @app.Reports.getReports(promised.years)`

I tried nesting promises but it exploded. I tried getting the years promise from inside the reports definition, but it exploded.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If suddenly you'll decide to use jQuery deferreds - there it's calles `pipe()` [link](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/);

Comment: @Kiril: No one would be crazy enough to go from Bluebird to jQuery. Btw, `pipe()` is deprecated (since 1.8)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nesting is the way to go here - without exploding, of course:

```
@app.Years.getYears()
.then (years) =>
    @app.Reports.getReports(years)
    .then (reports) ->
        console.log {years, reports}
```

You could not access `promised.years` in your `getReports` call, because it is not in scope - it's the parameter of the callback function that you pass in *after* having called `getReports` in the first place.

An alternative way to write this would be to construct the promises separately, and join them together with that `Promise.props` that you used:

```
yearsPromise = @app.Years.getYears()
reportsPromise = yearsPromise.then(@app.Reports.getReports)
Promise.props
    years: yearsPromise,
    reports: reportsPromise
.then (promised) ->
    console.log promised
```

(Notice that you [cannot refer to another property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572) in an object literal)

Comment: Thanks! I like the look of the second option, but I don't understand at what point the parameter would be passed into `getReports` as it's a function reference...

Comment: `Promise.join` does that for you - it waits for all arguments to resolve before calling your function. Actually, in this case it's an overcomplication, I'll replace it with a simpler mechanism

Comment: Great, thanks! I decided to go with the first option after all as it gives me finer-grained control over what I pass in, even though I'm not a fan of nesting in general. I think my initial nesting problem was that I was trying to do two `.prop()`s - either way, it works now. Cheers again :)

Comment: In case `getReports` is a method that uses `this` one can use `reportsPromise = yearsPromise.then(years => @app.Reports.getReports(years))`